# I can customize Overflow Menu but not default menu in Android

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, styles, themes

When I am using **Action Bar**, 
I can customize the **overflow menu** such as modifying background color and text size by applying a custom style to theme.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Some.Style</item>
</style>
```

However, when I press **hardware menu button**, 
it create a menu from **bottom of screen** which contains same items as overflow menu. 
Unfortunately, the **style** of this bottom menu is **not same** as overflow menu. 
It just uses the default style.

How can I customize the bottom menu style?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We can change the background of the Android >= 4.0 HW key bottom options menu by defining the android:panelBackground item in the theme.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:panelBackground">@drawable/mybackground</item>
</style>
```

The styling of text is not supported as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23499202/styling-textcolor-of-hardware-key-menu-paneltextappearance-not-honored)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to change background color of the menu at bottom when push physical menu button:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
           <item name="panelBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
   ...
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
```